# Confidence interval for number of successes in population in a hypergeometric distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, hypergeometric-distribution

I have a hypergeometric distribution with known $N$, $n$ and $k$ (following [the notation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution)) and I'd like to calculate the confidence interval for $K$.

I considered the Poisson approximation (but I'd like the confidence interval to be valid even for $K$ close to $N$).

What other options are there?

Comment: A Bayesian interval won't give you an interval with the properties of a confidence interval (won't give you a selected level of coverage for example). If you're contemplating both [credible intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval) and [confidence intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) at the same time, what properties are you looking for in an interval? What do you need this interval to actually do?

Comment: I know about the difference between credible and confidence intervals, I just forgot to say explicitly that Bayes' theorem wouldn't output a confidence interval. I don't want this for any specific purpose, only that I realized I don't know how to calculate confidence interval for $K$ in this context and I'd like to learn how; there are no additional requirements for the interval. Also, the confidence interval is meant to be for $K$ (the number of objects with some desirable feature), not $k$ (the number of successes).

Comment: On $K$: your question references the notation in the Wikipedia article; it defines $K$ there as the "number of success states in the population" while $k$ is the corresponding number in the sample. In this case "having some desirable feature" would be "success"

Comment: OK, I understand.

Comment: I removed the mention of Bayes' theorem to keep it about confidence intervals only.

Comment: [Similar subsequent question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/425236/how-to-compute-confidence-interval-in-a-case-with-small-sample-size-small-popul/425298#425298), with a possibly-relevant answer.